# Chrome Ignores Monospace Font Choice in Settings

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

In Chrome, I have the monospace font set to Courier 10 Pitch [image]

But when I'm filling in a web form, the font is a tiny serif instead:

[image]

Any ideas/suggestions on how to fix this are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The font settings in Chrome was not meant to override the settings provided by the Website. It will only take effect when webpage provides a generic name for fonts like *Serif*, or *Sans Serif* or the font name specified are not found. If a website specifies a font and that font is available in your computer or can be downloaded as a web-font, your settings will not take effect.

Here is a [Google forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/cVoKSp02nJ0) about same topic. The user Core says same there. But you can use an extension to force your settings take effect.

Here is one such extension. It's [Force custom fonts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E5%BC%BA%E5%88%B6%E7%BD%91%E9%A1%B5%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E5%AD%97%E4%BD%93/hckjchjpkmbihoocajjpjajkggbccgee). There should be many others to choose from.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I did try Force Custom Fonts, but there was no effect. I've asked in the wordpress.com forums; it seems to be a common problem there. I'll update here if I find a solution.